# Cant hide buttons given a condition "Health Bar"

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm comparing 2 lists. When I click the submit button, it compares the lists. If the lists didn't match the health bar, the block should hide 1 bar every time it can't compare.

[Click here to see a picture of the health bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwfL3.png)

```
        if (Input.SequenceEqual(OrderedList))
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "true both are 
        equal";
           
        }
        else
        {

            richTextBox1.Text = "false";

            int a = 0;
            while(a == 0)
            {   
                Health1.Hide();
                a++;
            }
            while (a == 1)
            {
                Health2.Hide();
               
                a++;
            }
            while (a == 2)
            {
                Health3.Hide();
                a++;
            }
      

        }
```

Comment: When you debug the code shown, what specifically is failing?  Which operation is producing an unexpected result?

Comment: its removing 3 health bars for a single click , the out come im looking for is when i cant compare it,  it only removes 1 bar then if the user clicks submit a second time it then will re compare and if it dosent match up then itll remove a second bar and the same logic for the 3rd bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
int a = 0;
while(a == 0)
{   
    Health1.Hide();
    a++;
}
while (a == 1)
{
    Health2.Hide();
    a++;
}
while (a == 2)
{
    Health3.Hide();
    a++;
}
```

Can be simplified to this:

```
Health1.Hide();
Health2.Hide();
Health3.Hide();
```

It's "hiding all three" because you're explicitly telling it to do that.  Consider the logic you've written:

- Set `a` to `0`.
- While (instead of `if` for some reason?) `a` is `0` (which it is, because you just set it to that)

  - Hide the first thing
  - Add `1` to `a`
- While (instead of `if` for some reason?) `a` is `1` (which it is, because you just added `1` to `0`, which is `1`)

  - Hide the second thing
  - Add `1` to `a`
- While (instead of `if` for some reason?) `a` is `2` (which it is, because you just added `1` to `1`, which is `2`)

  - Hide the third thing
  - Add `1` to `a`

It *sounds like* you want to track the number of times the user has clicked across multiple calls to this logic.  For that you'd need to store a value *outside this method*.  Consider a class-level value:

```
class WhateverYourClassIs
{
    private int numberOfClicks = 0;

    // the rest of your class members, methods, etc.
}
```

Then in your method you would examine that value.  You would use `if` statements for this, not *loops* (since you don't want to actually repeat anything, you're just checking a logical condition).  And you wouldn't want to *re-check* the value to see if it's been increased right after you've increased it, because that will *always* be true.

So perhaps something like this:

```
if (this.numberOfClicks == 0)
    Health1.Hide();
else if (this.numberOfClicks == 1)
    Health2.Hide();
else if (this.numberOfClicks == 2)
    Health3.Hide();
this.numberOfClicks++;
```

So with each click `this.numberOfClicks` is always incremented.  But before incrementing it you check what the current value is and perform your logic.

Comment: Thank you for your help, much appreciated.